# MySQL: Search for a sentence and ignore order of words

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there something in MySQL will allow to search for sentence without care about the order of words, ex: Search for `Europe league` match `league Europe`, same with sentences contain 3 words ... etc

I know I can handle this in Programming language and generate MySQL query like this:

```
select p.title
from post p
where p.title = 'Europe league' or p.title = 'league Europe'
order by case
    when text = 'Europe league' then 1
    when text = 'league Europe' then 2
end
limit 10;
```

But is there a self handle in MySQL for this issue? thx

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for full text search. Read up on [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html), so you can use the following kind of query:

```
SELECT p.title
FROM post p
WHERE MATCH (p.title) AGAINST ("+europe +league" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) @Jethro

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo. Remove the comma before IN BOOLEAN MODE.

Comment: It seems it require MyISAM with full text indexing support: (Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list)

Comment: When you're developing search functionality, you should always use boolean. In addition, rtfm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the number of iterations becomes prohibitive as you add more words; one solution to this would be to use the instr function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr).  That way you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
select p.title
from post p
where instr('Europe',p.title)>0
AND instr('League ',p.title)>0
AND instr('Match',p.title)>0
limit 10;
```

Comment: That is not really a scalable solution, is it?